# CheckBox in ListView setonclicklistener not working properly

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, onitemclicklistener, ischecked

I have a `ListView` with `CheckBox` and a `TextView` . In my adapters `getView()` method I implemented this listener on checkbox.

```
holder.check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HashMap<String, String> localMap = (HashMap<String, String>) holder.check
                    .getTag();
            if (holder.check.isChecked()) {
                trackinglist.add(localMap.get("taskid"));
                checkedlist.add(localMap.get("taskid"));
            } else {
                if (trackinglist.contains(localMap.get("taskid"))) {
                    trackinglist.remove(localMap.get("taskid"));
                }
                if (alreadycheckedlist.contains(localMap.get("taskid"))) {
                    undonelist.add(localMap.get("taskid"));
                    alreadycheckedlist.remove(localMap.get("taskid"));
                } else {
                    checkedlist.remove(localMap.get("taskid"));
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Now my problem is that the `holder.check.isChecked()` always returns false even when the `CheckBox` is clicked and it is checked . What might be causing this behavior ? and yes I dont want to use `setoncheckchangelistener` . Please Help.

Comment: Why don't u use View v directly?

Comment: how can i do that ? please give me some example .

Comment: @e7fendy any reason why that might be the problem?

Comment: When OnClick, you will get the view which is clicked. You can check if the holder.check is the same as v. If not, maybe holder.check is already past (because of orientation, etc). It is better to use View v directly, or findviewbyid.

Answer (score 1):

you may use

```
holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: please read the last line of the question. This method is called every time the checked value changes . I want it to be fired only when the user clicks on the check.